# exact regex match for multiple equal signs

Tags: regex

I am searching though a report that gets automatically generated. There are many sections and each section is separated by multiple "="(equal signs). I am wanting to create a simple script to basically extract certain data at a specific section. The only real determination of what section is what is based on the amount of equal signs.

How would I find only the "==" and not anything else?

```
====
===
==
=
```

I have used some light regex before and based on my very limited knowledge, I could do this for normal characters, such as `\ba{2}\b` however, trying to do this with `\b={2}\b` it does not work.

By doing the search as `={2}` I am able to locate any and all of the double equal signs.

What am I missing here? I am not able to find much on this type of problem I am running into.

Comment: `\b` matches only a certain set of characters. It depends on what is before and after the `==`.

Comment: `\b` means "word boundary". `=` is a word boundary. Try `^==$`.

Comment: I have tied `^==$` and `^={2}` and `^={2}$` none of these work. as soon as I add anything to the beginning it no longer locates anything.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: php most likely. However, I may use perl since most of the other reports being used are perl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simple regexp match only ==

```
(?<!=)==(?!=)
```

Negative lookbehind check there's no `=` before. Negative lookahead checks there's no `=` after.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: This did indeed work. I was able to modify what you provided to fit my needs nicely. 
`(?<!=)={2}(?!=)` worked very well.

Comment: Nice and well explained :)

Comment: Just curious, @TheChef: why the quantifier? How did that fit your needs better?

Comment: most of the reports I will be getting will need to have up to 100 "=" in them. So i will need to be able to adjust this number accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For those who reach this topic as me but...

...need to match **equal signs** within **various comparisons** syntax in the **source code** such as `=`, `==`, `===`, `!=`, `!==`, `>=`, `<=`, `+=`, `-=`, `++=`, `--=`, `=+`, `=-`, `=++`, `=--` can use slightly modified Hans Schindler's solution:

```
(?<!=)[!=<>+-]*=[+-]*(?!=)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/KCHiaw/1)